# Why I can't access directory with 755 permissions

Tags: ajax, permissions, file-permissions

I set the same permissions for all directories on my website (755 / drwxr-xr-x), and I can access all of them on localhost, but when i put it online there is problem with those, which haven't got index.html in it. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

I've got a page with directory 'images', from which I'm loading images using ajax call, and I'm getting 403 (You don't have permission to access (...)/images on this server.

Please help me, because it gives me a headache for quite a long time.

--- edit ---

I'll try to ask my question again as simple as I can: why can't I access URL http://myadress.com/images to browse images, while I can access http://myadress.com/images/1.jpg to see an image?

-- ANSWER --

Just as I thought, the answer was pretty simple. I added .htaccess file to images directory with Options +Indexes in it. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 Forbidden error means that your file has bad permissions. Directories and folders must be 755. Executable scripts within the cgi-bin folder must be 755. Images, media, and text files like HTML should be 755 or 644.

Comment: The problem is that all of my directories have 755. However, I can access only those of them, which has index.html in it. There must be some clear explanation for it, but I just can't find it. I guess I should have paid more attention on computer networks classes.